# Reference VC++ code or convert to DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, microsoft-metro

I am writing a new application that references a VC++ library that I have the solution and projects for. The version of Visual studio I am using (Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Windows 8) will not let me include the VC++ library in my new project, so is it better for me to somehow convert the old VC++ library to a DLL or manually include all of my library classes into my new project.

What are the best practices?

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to include the old library in your new project.  Bet it does not say "I won't let you".

Comment: It says Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 RC for Windows 8 only supports Metro Style App, dll, or lib projects

Comment: One "best practice" is to use the tools you need to get the job done.  VS2012 Express isn't it.

Comment: Hans Passant, not sure what you mean by that. I believe that is the only version of VS that you can build Metro apps on which is what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mistaken that new project doesn't support an old library. Why do you think so? 

But if it is really truth, its better to create a dynamic library and add it to project dependencies. And then simply invoke required functions

Comment: So does that mean I need to modify the existing library to include hooks into it that can be accessed when it is dll form?

Comment: you need to change project type